# Редактирование массива регулярным выражением

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Выбираю из базы сайта все короткие новости (`short_story`) через цикл, при этом необходимо оставить только текст и убрать изображения. Для этого использую регулярное выражение. Пример кода ниже. Регулярное выражение работает. Помогите разобраться новичку.

```
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $autor[$i]=$row['autor'];
  echo "Автор: ".$autor[$i]."<br>\n";

  $short_story[$i]=$row['short_story'];
  preg_match("!([А-Яа-я 0-9\-_!,.:#\\$+=?)(])*!si",$short_story[$i],$short_story[$i]);
  echo "Короткая новость: {$short_story[$i][1]}<br>\n";

  $alt_name[$i]=$row['alt_name'];
  echo "Папка: ".$alt_name[$i]."<br>\n";

  $date[$i]=explode(' ',$row['date']);
  echo "Дата: ".$date[$i][0]."<br>\n";

  echo "<hr>";
  $i++;
}
```

Вот то, что хранится в базе в поле `short_story`:

```
Сын накопил небольшую сумму денег к новому году, попросил купить продуктов, помочь сделать сендвичи и раздать бездомным в нашем городе.<br /> <p style=\"text-align:center;\"><img src=\"/uploads/posts/2014-12/1419680862_1.jpg\" /></p> <p>&nbsp;</p><br />
```

Comment: Что вызывает затруднение? Просто хотите разобраться, как работает регулярное выражение? Или что-то не устраивает в работе скрипта?

Comment: Данный скрпит не работает. В $short_story[$i][1] приходит пустой массив.

Comment: пример текста с базы можете привести?